# pagenote: Adding a cross-referencing mechanism

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, endnotes, pagenote

This question originates from a bug report at [SourceForge.net: biblatex](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2989094&group_id=244752&atid=1126005) from April 2010. A user pointed out that a certain `biblatex` style (`verbose-inote`) produced wrong references when used together with the [`pagenote`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pagenote.html) package (which, quoting from its documentation, "provides notes similar to footnotes except that they are typeset on a different page"). What follows is the response of Philipp Lehman, the author of `biblatex`:

> Looks like a bug in the pagenote
> package which does not seem to support
> \label in the pagenotes:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{scrartcl}
> \usepackage{pagenote}
> \makepagenote
> \begin{document}
> Text\pagenote{Page note.\label{test1}}
> Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test1}.}
> Text\pagenote{Another page note.\label{test2}}
> Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test2}.}
> \printnotes
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> It works fine with the endnotes
> package so I suggest you try that:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{scrartcl}
> \usepackage{endnotes}
> \begin{document}
> Text\endnote{Endnote.\label{test1}}
> Text\endnote{See note \ref{test1}.}
> Text\endnote{Another endnote.\label{test2}}
> Text\endnote{See note \ref{test2}.}
> \theendnotes
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> The verbose-inote style uses the
> \label+\ref mechanism. Since this is a
> standard LaTeX feature, I consider
> this a bug in/a limitation of the
> pagenote package.

Recently, I took a look into `endnotes.sty` (which also contains the package documentation) and stumbled upon the following change note:

> Modification by Dominik Wujastyk,
> London, 19 September 1991:
>
> Moved the line
>
> ```
> \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}
> ```
>
> out of the definition of @endnotetext
> and into the definition of @doanenote
> so that \label and \ref commands work
> correctly in endnotes.  Otherwise, the
> \label just pointed to the last
> section heading (or whatever)
> preceding the \theendnotes command.

This former bug of the `endnotes` package actually equates to the current behaviour of `pagenote`. It is unclear to me if the author of the `pagenote` package, Peter Wilson, did not want to include a cross-referencing mechanism or if `pagenote` suffers from a similar bug as `endnotes` once did, but for `biblatex`'s verbose-inote style, a `\label`+`\ref` mechanism in `pagenote` would be extremely useful.

By now, you may have guessed the actual question: *What modifications in / additions to `pagenote.sty` would be necessary to support the standard LaTeX cross-referencing mechanism?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I'v come up with what seems to be a solution. I suspect that my approach is rather long-winded and offers room for improvement.

Rummaging through `endnotes.sty` and `pagenote.sty`, I noticed that `endnotes` provided for writing more data in the `.ent` file (an auxiliary file that contains the text of endnotes). Basically, parts of the `\refstepcounter` mechanism (especially `\edef\@currentlabel`) were "sourced out". I experimented with `pagenote`'s single occurence of `\refstepcounter` in order to write data into the auxiliary file and at some point was partially successfull -- cross-references for pagenotes kind-of worked, but resetting the `pagenote` counter for new chapters/sections (the default behaviour without the `continuous` package option) was broken.

My currrent approach is to create a new counter that "mirrors" the `pagenote` counter. Every time the `\@wrpnote` macro increments the original counter, it also writes `\refstepcounter{pnotemirror}` into the `.ent` auxiliary file, and every time the value of the original counter is 0 (i.e., has been reset by a `\chapter` or `\section` command), the "mirror" counter is also reset. Clumsy, but it seems to work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
  continuous% Default: pagenote counter is reset with new chapters/sections
]{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{pnotemirror}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@wrpnote}[2][]{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{pagenote}}{0}% NEW
    {\@pnwrite\@notefile{}{\string\setcounter{pnotemirror}{0}}}% NEW
    {}% NEW
  \refstepcounter{pagenote}%
  \notenumintext{\thepagenote}%
  \ifpnhaschapter
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
      \addtonotes{\pagenotesubhead{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
      \addtonotes{\pagenotesubhead{\thesection}{}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \@pnwrite\@notefile{}
%     {\string\noteentry{\thepagenote}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}}% DELETED
    {\string\refstepcounter{pnotemirror}\string\noteentry{\thepagenote}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}}% NEW
  \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

Text\pagenote{Page note.\label{test1}}
Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test1}.}
Text\pagenote{Another page note.\label{test2}}
Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test2}.}

\section{bar}

Text\pagenote{Page note.\label{test3}}
Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test3}.}
Text\pagenote{Another page note.\label{test4}}
Text\pagenote{See note \ref{test4}.}

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class emulates the functionality of the `pagenote` package and therefore suffers from the same bug. Because `memoir` uses different macro names, for the sake of convenience here's a "patch" for `memoir` (to be added in the document preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{pnotemirror}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\m@m@wrpnote}[2][]{%
  \@ifmtarg{#1}{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{pagenote}}{0}%
      {\m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}{\string\setcounter{pnotemirror}{0}}}%
      {}%
    \refstepcounter{pagenote}%
    \notenumintext{\thepagenote}}{}%
  \ifm@mpn@new@chap
    \global\m@mpn@new@chapfalse
    \addtonotes{\string\pagenotesubhead{\@chapapp}{\thechapter}{\pnchap}}%
  \fi
  \ifm@mpn@new@schap
    \global\m@mpn@new@schapfalse
    \addtonotes{\string\pagenotesubhead{\@chapapp}{}{\pnschap}}%
  \fi
  \m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}
    {\string\refstepcounter{pnotemirror}\string\noteentry{\thepagenote}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Using the memoir flavor ([MWE](http://pastebin.com/xGMpacbw)), I get: `! Use of \\m@m@wrpnote doesn't match its definition.
\protected@write ...le@protect \edef \reserved@a {
                                                  \write #1{#3}}\reserved@a ...
l.36 Text\pagenote{Page note.\label{test1}}`