# memoir: Using pagenote number in index

Tags: memoir, indexing

Using the MakeIndex (via `memoir` class), I would like to index a  page note by referencing the **page number** (in the Notes section where the note appears) as well as the **note number**. Attempts to include `\thepagenote` somewhere references the number of the last page note in the document.

For example, given the MWE below that has 4 page notes, **attempts to index the first page note** ends up with an entry in the index referencing the **last (fourth) page note**.

I noticed that the `.ind` file still has `\thepagenote` while page numbers are hardcoded after all processing is done, e.g.

```latex
\item First pagenote, \ipn{\thepagenote}{5}.
```

so I guess I have to figure out some way of expanding `\thepagenote` sooner. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282591/index-inside-footnote-how-to-propagate-the-footnote-number-correctly-with-inde/282610#282610) seems closely related, but porting that solution directly did not seem to produce expected results -- a number for `\thepagenote` is hardcoded into the `.ind` file, but it is still the last page note.

[image]

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\ipn}[2]{PAGE #2 NOTE #1}

\makeindex
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\index{1st index term}%
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{First pagenote\index{2nd index term|ipn{\thepagenote}}}
\lipsum[2]\pagenote{Second pagenote}
\lipsum[3]\pagenote{Third pagenote}
\lipsum[4]\pagenote{Fourth pagenote}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes
\printindex
\end{document}
```

## MWE like referenced answer

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282610/47128

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}

\makeatletter
\let\if@nopgnote\iffalse % just for the example
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
  \if@nopgnote
    \index{#1}%
  \else
    \edef\tempnumber{\thepagenote}%
    \expandafter\pagenoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pagenoteindex}[2]{\index{#2|pn{#1}}}

\makeindex
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{First pagenote}
\lipsum[2]\pagenote{Second pagenote.\is{inside second pagenote}}
\lipsum[3]\pagenote{Third pagenote.}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9574/pagenote-adding-a-cross-referencing-mechanism?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somewhat blindly combined the answers I referenced previously:

- [pagenote: Adding a cross-referencing mechanism](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14531/47128) -- updated the provided code for more recent version of memoir class
- [\index inside footnote: How to propagate the footnote number correctly with index package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282610/47128) -- adapted for pagenotes

And the result is below. The changes to the memoir command `\m@m@wrpnote` could maybe be condensed with `\xpatchcmd` but I'm not familiar with that. Additions to the original command are marked with `BEGIN ADDITIONS`.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}

\makeatletter
\let\if@noftnote\iffalse % just for the example
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
  \edef\tempnumber{\thepnotemirror}%
  \expandafter\pagenoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pagenoteindex}[2]{\index{#2|pn{#1}}}


\newcounter{pnotemirror}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\m@m@wrpnote}[2][]{%
  \mem@pn@lastkern=\lastkern%
  \refstepcounter{pagenoteshadow}%
  \ifm@mpnpageopt%
    \phantomsection%
    \label{pagenote\thepagenoteshadow-\thesheetsequence}%
  \fi%
  \if\mem@pn@step%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{% BEGIN ADDITION
      \ifnumequal{\value{pagenote}}{0}%
      {\m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}{\string\setcounter{pnotemirror}{0}}}%
      {}% END ADDITION
      \refstepcounter{pagenote}%
      % this enables the ^{1,2} feature
      \ifdim\mem@pn@lastkern=\multiplefootnotemarker%
        \m@mmf@prepare% rerun
      \fi%
      \mem@pn@multiple@marker{\notenumintext{\thepagenote}}%
    }{\m@mmf@prepare}%
  \fi%
  \ifm@mpn@new@chap%
    \global\m@mpn@new@chapfalse%
    \addtonotes{\string\pagenotesubhead{\@chapapp}{\thechapter}{\pnchap}}%
  \fi%
  \ifm@mpn@new@schap%
    \global\m@mpn@new@schapfalse%
    \addtonotes{\string\pagenotesubheadstarred{\@chapapp}{}{\pnschap}}%
  \fi%
  \m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}%
    {% BEGIN ADDITION
      \string\refstepcounter{pnotemirror}% END ADDITION
      \string\startnoteentry{\thepagenote}}%
  \m@m@pnwrited\@notefile{}{{#1}}%
  \m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}%
    {{pagenote\thepagenoteshadow-\thesheetsequence}}%
  \m@m@pnwrite@fourtharg{#1}%
  \begingroup%
    \newlinechar='40%
    \m@m@pnwrited\@notefile{}{#2}%
  \endgroup%
  \m@m@pnwrite\@notefile{}%
  {\string\endnoteentry}%
  \endgroup%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother

\makeindex
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\index{Some index term}%
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{Ch. 1, First pagenote}
\lipsum[2]\pagenote{Ch. 1, Second pagenote\is{Ch. 1, Second pagenote}}
\lipsum[3]\pagenote{Ch. 1, Third pagenote}
\lipsum[4]\pagenote{Ch. 1, Fourth pagenote}
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[5]\pagenote{Ch. 2, First pagenote}
\lipsum[6]\pagenote{Ch. 2, Second pagenote}
\lipsum[7]\pagenote{Ch. 2, Third pagenote\is{Ch. 2, Third pagenote}}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes
\printindex
\end{document}
```