# Detecting unused packages in LaTeX document

Tags: packages, best-practices

I have quite a bad habit of copy-and-pasting my packages from one LaTeX document to another. Is there any way we can detect unused packages (i.e. `\usepackage` commands) so that they can be removed from the LaTeX document?

Comment: You can try to remove a package and compile to detect whether or not you need it. Do this again and again until the last package. :-)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ This might become difficult if you're using packages that don't necessarily provide new macros, but change existing things, e.g. `microtype`.

Comment: @doncherry: But our eyes can detect it :-) We should do an educated approach when removing the packages.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ I'm not sure where an educated approach is gonna get you if you don't know why you added which package, i.e. you don't know what changes you're looking for, in a potentially lengthy document. (For my general take on using packages, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41715/4012)

Comment: I guess the best thing would be _not_ to paste a complete preamble but to start with an empty one. Then you only add a new package if you need it. This way you (a) don't have unused packages and (b) know what each package is used for. A bonus: after doing so for a few documents you might be able to answer the question yourself :)

Comment: Load only the basic packages (`fontenc`, `inputenc` for `pdflatex`; `fontspec` for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX) and possibly `babel` or `polyglossia`; load other ones only when you need them. Exceptions might by `microtype` `array` and `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg and `booktabs`? @all: If you have more general advice on using packages, go ahead and add it to [Barebones or Packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41685/barebones-or-packages)!

Comment: @doncherry You're right: `booktabs` is definitely recommended (if you have tables in your document).

Comment: @egreg What about `amsmath` (or `mathtools`)?

Comment: @Guido The first is definitely recommended when doing math; but each field has its "mandatory" packages, so I was being as generic as possible.

Comment: What about ``fixltx2e``?

Comment: One could write a script to compile the file, copy the output in a temp folder, then compile the file again with the N-th `\usepackage` commented out (that could be done using sed?), and compare outputs.  Are you using Windows, Mac, or Linux?  If the latter, I might try if no one does it before me.

Answer (score 26):

Packages in LaTeX (or other format flavors in  fact) are essentially of three different types:

1. Packages that extend the functionality of LaTeX (e.g., `multicol` provides additional commands and environments to balance columns)
2. Packages that modify the behavior and layout without providing any additional functionality
3. Hybrid packages that do both of the above.

Most packages are of type 1) and 3), that is packages that are mostly only changing layout, still usually offer some additional functionality to parameterize, e.g., `geometry`'s main purpose is to set page layout dimension, but in order to do so it offers additional commands to customize it (this is of type 3) not 2)). But bottom line all 3 types exist.

#### Packages of type 1

If you don't use the additional functionality then loading or not loading it should make no difference whatsoever. So if you only have such packages then the test would be: "comment the loading out and if the document compiles you don't need the package".

#### Packages of type 2

Here the situation is different: if you don't load them the document would still compile, but the output would be different. So in this case the test should be on any change to the output produced.

A simple test approach would be to add `\showoutput` in the preamble. That would generate for each output page a precise symbolic content structrue in the `.log` file which could be compared.

The logs would need a bit of cleanup first so that other things are not compared as well, but essentially that would tell you: has the file change when I didn't load the package.

Now, if a package is of this type why doesn't it always changes the behavior of all documents? Simply because it may only change some aspects and those specific ones do not appear in the current document.

#### Packages of type 3

Being a hybrid, you will need to test for both, if you do not use the extended features (which would break your document when missing) you might still have a layout difference.

## Conclusion

As there is no proper classification available into which bucket a package falls, one has to assume that they are all of type 3 and accordingly watch out for layout differences when compiling without the package. Missing functionality will be tested for free (as they will result in an error).

Full automation of such a test might be a bit difficult to program but not that hard.

Answer (score 21):

I tried my hand at implementing [Frank Mittelbach's proposal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79276/2707) of removing packages one at a time, testing for each one whether removing it changes the output.

This is done automatically by a script written purely in LaTeX (which requires the `--shell-escape`).  The resulting code is very slow: it has to run TeX on the file many times (twice the number of packages), and TeX is not the fastest tool to parse the resulting log file (that step could be made faster, actually).

To use it, store the following code in a file, say `packagecheck.tex`, and call `pdflatex --shell-escape packagecheck <engine> <filename>` where `<engine> <filename>` is the command you would usually type.

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78073/detecting-unused-packages-in-latex-document?lq=1
\ifnum\pdfshellescape=1\else
  \PackageError{packagecheck}
    {Misused\MessageBreak
      pdflatex --shell-escape packagecheck\MessageBreak
      <engine> <file-name>}
    {}
  \csname @@end\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname bye\expandafter\endcsname
\fi
\RequirePackage{expl3, l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% \begin{macro}{\log_map_inline:nn, \log_map_inline:Vn}
%   \begin{syntax}
%     \cs{log_map_inline:nn} \Arg{file name} \Arg{code}
%   \end{syntax}
%   Goes through the file \meta{file name}\texttt{.log} and performs the
%   \meta{code} for each logical line of the log file (assuming that any
%   line with $79$ characters in the log file is to be concatenated with
%   the following one).  The \meta{code} receives the line as |#1|, as a
%   string.  For instance the following shows each line in |texput.log|.
%   \begin{verbatim}
%     \log_map_inline:nn { texput } { \tl_show:n {#1} }
%   \end{verbatim}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\int_const:Nn \c_log_line_count_int { 79 }
\int_new:N \l_log_line_int
\int_new:N \l_log_max_line_int
\ior_new:N \g_log_ior
\str_new:N \l_log_line_str
\str_new:N \l_log_tmp_str
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__log_tmp:n #1 { }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_map_inline:nn #1#2 % not nestable
  {
%<*trace>
    \int_zero:N \l_log_line_int
    \ior_open:Nn \g_log_ior { #1 . log }
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_log_ior { \int_incr:N \l_log_line_int }
    \ior_close:N \g_log_ior
    \msg_term:n
      {
        Opening~file~#1.log~( \int_use:N \l_log_line_int \ lines).~
        One~dot~per~100~lines.
      }
    \int_zero:N \l_log_line_int
%</trace>
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \__log_tmp:n ##1 {#2}
    \ior_open:Nn \g_log_ior { #1 . log }
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_log_ior
      {
%<*trace>
        \int_incr:N \l_log_line_int
        \if_int_compare:w \l_log_line_int > 100 \scan_stop:
          \tex_message:D { . }
          \int_zero:N \l_log_line_int
        \fi:
%</trace>
        \str_set:Nn \l_log_tmp_str {##1}
        \tl_set_eq:NN \l_log_line_str \l_log_tmp_str
        \int_until_do:nNnn
          { \str_count:N \l_log_tmp_str } < \c_log_line_count_int
          {
            \ior_get_str:NN \g_log_ior \l_log_tmp_str
            \str_put_right:Nx \l_log_line_str \l_log_tmp_str
          }
        \exp_args:No \__log_tmp:n \l_log_line_str
      }
    \ior_close:N \g_log_ior
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \log_map_inline:nn { V }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\log_get_packages:nN, \log_get_packages:VN}
%   \begin{macrocode}
\seq_new:N \l_log_packages_seq
\seq_new:N \l_log_tmp_seq
\regex_const:Nn \c_package_regex { \w* \. sty }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_get_packages:nN #1#2
  {
    \seq_clear:N \l_log_packages_seq
    \log_map_inline:nn {#1}
      {
        \regex_extract_all:NnN \c_package_regex {##1} \l_log_tmp_seq
        \seq_concat:NNN \l_log_packages_seq
          \l_log_packages_seq \l_log_tmp_seq
      }
    \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l_log_packages_seq
    \tl_set:Nx #2
      { \seq_map_function:NN \l_log_packages_seq \prg_do_nothing: }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \log_get_packages:nN { V }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\log_get_pages:nN}
%   \begin{macrocode}
\tl_new:N \l_log_pages_tl
\str_new:N \l_log_page_str
\bool_new:N \l_log_in_page_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_get_pages:nN #1#2
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_log_pages_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l_log_page_str
    \bool_set_false:N \l_log_in_page_bool
    \log_map_inline:nn {#1} % could be optimized away
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l_log_in_page_bool
          {
            \tl_if_empty:nTF {##1}
              {
                \bool_set_false:N \l_log_in_page_bool
                \tl_put_right:Nx \l_log_pages_tl { { \l_log_page_str } }
              }
              { \str_put_right:Nx \l_log_page_str { ##1 \iow_newline: } }
          }
          {
            \str_if_eq_x:nnT
              { Completed } { \__log_get_pages_test:ww ##1 ~ \q_stop }
              {
                \str_if_eq_x:nnT
                  { Completed~box~being~shipped~out~ }
                  { \str_substr:nnn {##1} { 1 } { 32 } }
                  {
                    \bool_set_true:N \l_log_in_page_bool
                    \str_put_right:Nx \l_log_page_str { ##1 \iow_newline: }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \l_log_pages_tl
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__log_get_pages_test:ww #1 ~ #2 \q_stop {#1}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \log_get_pages:nN { V }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}[aux]{\__run:n}
%   Compile the file once, halting if there is an error, and in
%   batchmode to suppress the output.  First output a line to separate
%   the output of the internal \TeX{} run from the main run.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__run:n #1
  {
    \iow_term:x { }
    \tex_immediate:D \tex_write:D 18
      {
        \l_run_engine_str \c_space_tl
        -halt-on-error \c_space_tl
        -interaction=batchmode \c_space_tl
        '\tl_to_str:n { #1 \input }' \c_space_tl
        \l_run_file_str
      }
  }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
\str_new:N \l_run_engine_str
\str_new:N \l_run_file_str
\tl_new:N \l_run_packages_tl
\tl_new:N \l_run_normal_pages_tl
\tl_new:N \l_run_pages_tl
\seq_new:N \l_run_used_packages_seq
\seq_new:N \l_run_unused_packages_seq
\int_new:N \l_run_package_int
\int_new:N \l_run_package_max_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__run_get_pages:nN #1#2
  {
    \__run:n {#1}
    \__run:n { #1 \loggingoutput \batchmode }
    \log_get_pages:VN \l_run_file_str #2
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \run:ww #1~#2~
  {
    \str_set:Nx \l_run_engine_str {#1}
    \str_set:Nx \l_run_file_str {#2}
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \. tex \Z } { } \l_run_file_str
    \__run:n { }
    \log_get_packages:VN \l_run_file_str \l_run_packages_tl
    \__run_get_pages:nN { } \l_run_normal_pages_tl
%<*trace>
    \int_set:Nn \l_run_package_max_int { \tl_count:N \l_run_packages_tl }
    \int_zero:N \l_run_package_int
%</trace>
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_run_packages_tl
      {
%<*trace>
        \int_incr:N \l_run_package_int
        \msg_term:n
          {
            Package~\int_use:N \l_run_package_int                 of~\int_use:N \l_run_package_max_int
          }
%</trace>
        \__run_get_pages:nN
          { \expandafter \let \csname ver @ ##1 \endcsname \empty }
          \l_run_pages_tl
        \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_run_pages_tl \l_run_normal_pages_tl
          { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_run_unused_packages_seq {##1} }
          { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_run_used_packages_seq {##1} }
      }
    \seq_if_empty:NF \l_run_used_packages_seq
      {
        \msg_info:nnxx { run } { used-packages }
          { \seq_count:N \l_run_used_packages_seq }
          {
            \seq_use:Nnnn \l_run_used_packages_seq
              { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
          }
      }
    \seq_if_empty:NF \l_run_unused_packages_seq
      {
        \msg_warning:nnxx { run } { unused-packages }
          { \seq_count:N \l_run_unused_packages_seq }
          {
            \seq_use:Nnnn \l_run_unused_packages_seq
              { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
          }
      }
    \msg_term:n
      {
        \fp_to_tl:n { round(\pdfelapsedtime/65536,1) }
        \ seconds
      }
    \tex_end:D
  }
\msg_new:nnn { run } { used-packages }
  {
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 1 }
      { The~package~#2~is~useful~in~this~document }
      { The~#1~packages~#2~are~useful~in~this~document. }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { run } { unused-packages }
  {
    Removing~
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 1 } { the~package~ } { any~of~the~packages~ }
    #2~changes~nothing~in~the~resulting~output.
  }
\use:n
  {
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \tex_endinput:D
    \exp_after:wN \run:ww
  }%
```

As I said, this is very slow, for instance, running `pdflatex --shell-escape packagecheck pdflatex test.tex` on the file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsgen}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

takes 5 minutes on my laptop before telling me that `amsgen` is not used in the document, but `lipsum` is.

How it works: the main tool is to call `\immediate\write18{<engine> -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode <TeX code> <filename>}` where `<engine>` is, for instance, `pdflatex`, `-halt-on-error` ensures that TeX won't try to continue beyond the first error (there will be errors when removing some packages), `-interaction=batchmode` minimizes the output of the "internal" runs, `<TeX code>` is some code that varies with the different runs, and `<filename>` is, well, the name of the file to compile.

- First run with no extra code.  This produces a log file in which we look for everything that matches `\w*.sty` (word characters followed by `sty`).  Perhaps I should search for `[\w\-]*.sty` instead, or something else.
- Then run twice to produce the correct output, first without and then with `\loggingoutput\batchmode`, which ensures that (1) the output pages are detailed in the log file (2) nothing more is written to the terminal.
- Then for each package, run twice, first without and then with `\loggingoutput\batchmode`, disabling the loading of that particular package by defining `\ver@<package name>.sty` prior to each run, to make LaTeX believe that the package is already loaded.  Compare the pages found in the log file to the normal pages found in the previous step to find out if the package is useful.
- Finally, show the list of all useless packages, and the time elapsed.

Comment: Very impressive, but can be fooled :-) I tested on a 'real' one page document where I know that all of the packages I load are used. Only takes 65 seconds on my system to test 34 packages it identifies, but some of these are loaded by others and are misunderstood (e.g. `graphics`, `etex`, `trig`). I guess the challenge there is that none of these are loaded by the main `.tex` file, but telling this would be hard. (You'd need to check for `( ... )` and allow for the fact that a file which is `\input` is different from a package.)

Comment: Also, a bigger test (a lecture course: around 120 pages of `beamer`) simply killed everything :-)

Comment: @JosephWright I'd say that declaring some packages that are not directly loaded as useless is a feature, but I agree that it would be nicer if there was a toggle for that.  Presumably, after finding a package, we'd want to ignore any package until one more `)` than `(` (indicating that we leave the package).  Can you be more explicit on "killed everything"?  My guess is that there isn't enough memory for the 120 pages.  One solution would be to compute a hash of each page, or something like that.

Comment: My point about packages is that if package X loads package Y to cover all of its functions, but you only use some parts of package X then you won't see a difference on excluding package Y, but can't remove it from the preamble of the `.tex` file. On 'killed everything', pdfTeX ran out of memory. I loaded `pdftexcmds` and used `\pdf@shellescape` which allows LuaTeX to be used: works fine but was going to take a _long_ time (log file 78k lines took around one hour to parse!).

Comment: @JosephWright I'm trying to see if there could be a faster way to do things.

Comment: Surely if package X loads package Y and you load package X, you can safely remove package Y from your preamble. Of course, it will still be loaded by package X but you don't need it in the preamble if package X will load it anyway, do you?

Comment: @cfr You are right, and my code does not detect this case, since I am preventing all of the package's code from being loaded.

Comment: @bruno-le-floch It seems to be an exercise in theory only and useless in practice! I tried on about 100 files of papers from 5 to 10 pages and almost every single one of them it process for a while and the comes back with: `Runaway definition?
->{Completed box being shipped out [61]
\vbox(539.46426+0.0)x326.0686
.\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\l_log_page_str ....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\OT\ETC.
                                                  
<*> packagecheck pdflatex main
                              
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch And here is a simple file that process very quickly but the result is wrong: It says you can remove `amssymb.sty` while you really can't:  `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb Q$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for a solution to this question myself and stumbled upon this tex.SE topic. Realizing that there is no real solution to the problem, I took the liberty to write a simple utility script to solve this problem.

The utility is written in Python, it is open source, and is accessible here: https://github.com/bazzilic/LaTeXpkges. More info on how it works is in the readme at github.

It is written for use on Windows platform and may not work on other platforms. It is currently in a very basic form, and I have only tested it on my thesis (it worked fine). You can either download the script if you have Python installed on the system, or go to the Release tab and download a zip with the Windows executable (created using py2exe).

**Important:** do **not** run it against your original files! Make a copy and run it against the copy!

Comment: I am wondering how this really work! Even if the PDF files have the same content, they will NOT have the same metadata (the generation date will be different even if by a few seconds) and so the md5sums will be completely different! What am I missing here ?

Comment: @PauloNey before comparison, the script goes through the PDF and removes the metadata that is typically created by pdflatex.

Answer (score 9):

The solution by Vasily Sidorov (@Bazzilic) above was quite a starter, but had a number of limitations, it ran on Windows only, limited to pdflatex, edited the original project .tex files,...

After some lack of contact with Vasily, I forked the code and it now runs on Linux as well as Windows. You can choose any of the latex engines: latex, pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex as well as BibTeX or BibLaTeX for biblio processing. It runs on a copy of your src code and has a --debug flag that leaves behind all intermediary files.

I also added a --visual option that converts the DVI/PDF files into high-res JPG's and compares them despite differences at the PDF level.

It has been extensively tested and it is working beautifully. Of course we want to hear from other testers and suggestions for improvement.

Code is available at:

```
https://github.com/TarasKuzyo/LaTeXpkges
```

Comment: +1 this is awesome! Idea for improvement: Do the builds in parallel to get a nice 2-4x speedup. :) Also, slight bug: `tmp_file.replace('.tex', '')` is wrong; it should only do this replacement at the end of the file name.