# Generate list of undefined control sequences/used newcommands

Tags: macros

I have a long tex file which uses many newcommands/providecommands sourced in from a separate file using `\input{}`. To upload to a preprint server I would like to keep only those commands which are really needed. Therefore I wonder how to generate a list of newcommands names to extract from the input file. Assuming all of these are defined as single lines it would be quite easy to extract them. My first approach was to comment the `\input`-statement to get a list `Undefined control sequence` errors and to generate the list from it. However the latex output is a little difficult to parse. Is there a switch to latex which allows me to extract a useful list more easily or some different approach?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78073/detecting-unused-packages-in-latex-document

Comment: The cmdtrack package would seem useful here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmdtrack

Comment: `grep -A 1 "Undefined control sequence" filename.log`

Comment: The package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/occam seems a bit odd, at least I can't understand how to use it. I'm mentioning it just in case.

Comment: The package ``occam`` requires programs that only work in the original MacOS. It is no longer usable nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`cmdtrack`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmdtrack) can be useful. Of course you can use the Terminal to search the log-file:

```
grep -ni -A 1 "Undefined control sequence" <filename>.log
```