# How to make a list of used custom macros

Tags: macros

I used to have a separate file where I store my custom macros. It is nothing more than a huge list of `\newcommands` and `\NewDocumentCommands`.

Now, I have a little note that I would like to share with a buddy of mine. I would like to send him a selfcontained LaTeX file, where all the custom macros that I use in the this particular note are included in the header. I don't like to copy-paste **all** the macros in the header, because I use only a small number of them. Is there a better way than to scan manually through my note and include the macros one by one?

For a better understanding here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{macros.tex}
    \newcommand{\macroA}{A}
    \newcommand{\macroB}{B}
    \newcommand{\macroC}{C}
    \newcommand{\macroD}{D}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \input{macros.tex}
    \macroA and \macroD
\end{document}
```

I would like to generate the following list:

- `\macroA`
- `\macroD`

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution with the help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81967/generate-list-of-undefined-control-sequences-used-newcommands?rq=1).

I use the package [`cmdtrack`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmdtrack) and afterwards `awk` to scan my `log`-File. (`grep` or similar program would also be possible.)

The slightly changed MWE looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{macros.tex}
    \newcommand{\macroA}{A}
    \newcommand{\macroB}{B}
    \newcommand{\macroC}{C}
    \newcommand{\macroD}{D}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{cmdtrack}
\input{macros.tex}

\begin{document}
    \macroA{} and \macroD{}
\end{document}
```

After compilation I run the following `awk`-command:

```
awk ' /was used on line/ { print $1 }' <file>.log
```

The result is the following list:

```
"macroA"
"macroD"
```

For macros with `\newcommands` this works but not for macros with `\NewDocumentsCommands`.

Comment: Where does `\NewDocumentCommand` come from?

Comment: @daleif the `\NewDocumentCommand` comes from the package [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Comment: ahh, my bad, I've always just `\DeclareDocumentCommand` when using `xparse`. Since `xparse` is LTX3, there might be a module for it, otherwise ask on the LTX3 list. Though, I've forgotten how I subscribed to it.

Comment: @daleif You should consider switching to `\NewDocumentCommand`, because `\DeclareDocumentCommand` overwrites any previous definition (like `\def`) while `\NewDocumentCommand` checks if there is already one defined (like `\newcommand`).