# Printing on A4 - standard classes vs. KOMA-Script classes

Tags: margins, koma-script, best-practices, paper-size

As I'm located in Europe the standard paper size is `A4`. So far I was normally using either `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` or even simply `\documentclass{article}`. Recently I spotted sections (1.1) and (1.2) in [An essential guide to LaTeX2ε usage](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) and realized that I might be doing something wrong.

Neither of the above possibilities is a *deadly sin*, but I'm confused with respect to the possibility of using `scrartcl.cls` class from the `KOMA -Script` bundle instead. Is it superior to the ones I'm using?

The `KOMA-Script` option yields smaller margins (which I like), but on the other hand results in a slightly longer (in terms of number of pages) document. At least for one testcase I tested. This is, to me, somehow counter intuitive.

What is the relation between the 2.5 possibilities? Which one is preferable for a european user?

Comment: Related: [Why should I *not* use the Koma-Script classes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73141/why-should-i-not-use-the-koma-script-classes). Maybe this already answers your question?

Comment: Customizing the margins is quite easy with `article` using `geometry`. If you're writing a paper for a submission, then it's probably better using the generic `article` so as to be sure of not using the wealth of commands and functions provided by KoMa-Script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides featuring smaller margins, the `KOMA-Script` classes also use a default font size of 11pt (instead of 10pt as the standard classes) -- that's why the number of pages in your test document increased. Smaller margins as well as a larger font size are good typographic strategies to deal with A4 paper; see [Why are default LaTeX margins so big?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big) for details and other options.

You can emulate `KOMA-Script`'s settings with the standard classes plus packages like `geometry`, but if you're looking for an "out-of-the-box" solution for A4 paper, the `KOMA-Script` classes are preferable.

EDIT: Here's an emulation of `KOMA-Script`'s settings using `article`/`geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.7,vmarginratio={1:2},heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}​
```