# enumerate ignores right margin in items with long words

Tags: margins, enumerate

I'm having trouble with an enumerate list and some "\item"s that contain longer words. Here LaTeX fails to do a line break and "ignores" my right margin (see \items No. 2 & 5 in my example). I could manually fix this by inserting possible manual breaks (-) in the longer words (see \item No. 3) but that can't be the proper solution, can it? Setting an [rightmargin=2.00cm] in the enumerate-environment didn't change anything about this. I don't mind having a line-break in-between words, as long as the rest of the item-text is justified

Any ideas where my mistake might be? Thank you very much, yours Sascha

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, fontsize=12bp]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.00cm,rmargin=2.00cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item{Wirklich langes Item: \blindtext}
    \item{Welchen Einfluss hat die Kongruenz zwischen dem Interventions- und dem Prüfungsformat auf das Ergebnis einer Studie zum Butterfly-Effect?}
    \item{Welchen Einfluss hat die Kongruenz zwischen dem Interventions- und dem Prüfungs"-format auf das Ergebnis einer Studie zum Butterfly-Effect?}
    \item{Ein etwas längeres Item, aber ich benutze einfach mal ganz andere Wörter und gucke dann mal, was hier passiert.}
    \item{Ein noch längeres Item, indem ich nun zunächstaber wirklichdeutlich längerundkompliziertere Wörter verwende}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Also you remove all this braces in the list.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @UlrikeFischer has said in her comment above, delete the `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` line and make sure your packages are up-to-date. It is also recommended to use the standard settings for a KOMA Script document,  `twoside=false`, `fontsize=12pt`, etc. Here is a working code:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false, a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.00cm,rmargin=2.00cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Wirklich langes Item: \blindtext
    \item Welchen Einfluss hat die Kongruenz zwischen dem Interventions- und dem Prüfungsformat auf das Ergebnis einer Studie zum Butterfly-Effect?
    \item Welchen Einfluss hat die Kongruenz zwischen dem Interventions- und dem Prüfungs"-format auf das Ergebnis einer Studie zum Butterfly-Effect?
    \item Ein etwas längeres Item, aber ich benutze einfach mal ganz andere Wörter und gucke dann mal, was hier passiert.
    \item Ein noch längeres Item, indem ich nun zunächstaber wirklichdeutlich längerundkompliziertere Wörter verwende
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `\item` does  *not* take an argument delimited by `{` and `}`, I would remove those symbols from the material that follows the five `\item` statements.

Comment: `It is also recommended to use the standard settings for a KOMA Script document, [twoside=false, a4paper, fontsize=12pt], etc. ` Really? Since when? If they are default, they don't need to be specified, but it is news to me that KOMA is not recommended for North American users. Why would it be bad to use double-sided with KOMA (as is standard for book) or 11pt? It is recommended not to use `geometry` or `setspace` with KOMA unless you really have to - better to use KOMA's facilities if you can - but that has nothing to do with the problem the OP is concerned with in the question.

Comment: @cfr KOMA is recommended for all users, I meant specifically `12bp` should be `12pt` and `oneside` should be `twoside=false` I just copied the whole line including `a4paper`. The authors can choose whatever they want, oneside, twoside, doubleside, singlespacing, doublespacing, .... nothing is incorrect. If you read the KOMA doc., you see `twoside=simple switch` and never `oneside`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130430/switch-to-one-side-layout-in-koma-script-scrbook, and this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96139/printing-on-a4-standard-classes-vs-koma-script-classes?rq=1

Comment: `oneside` is valid as a class option. It is not valid if passed directly to `\KOMAoptions` by the user. I agree about `12bp` but your answer suggested to me that the options as written were all recommended which is not the case (and not what you meant). Maybe you could clarify some of this a bit?