# koma script classes versus ordinary classes

Tags: scrbook

Regarding koma script classes, are they preferred over ordinary classes, what are the main differences and when to use each?

Also I am making a book, which is prefferred: memoir, scr book or ordinary book class? are there any diffetences regarding packages, unicode fonts, compiling....

Comment: your question is like asking whether red or yellow is preferred, there are many document classes written by many different people, latex is explicitly designed to make that possible. You can not ask in general which is preferred.

Comment: You might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7742/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73141/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1351/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988/35864. But I don't think one can really say that KOMA-Script classes are 'preferred' over the standard classes (or the other way round): Many people use the KOMA-Script classes because they like the additional features they get or because the like the default output more than the default output of the standard classes. Many people use the standard classes because they offer sufficient features ...

Comment: ... or because they like the looks of it. Some people use `memoir` some the AMS classes. For most basic LaTeX features and packages it doesn't if you load the standard classes or KOMA-Script classes, they are usually supported equally well, but some packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script, mainly when KOMA-Script implements similar functionalities out of the box or with KOMA-Script packages (`fancyhdr` comes to mind).