# The document class to recommend for a PhD report

Tags: thesis, report

I am writing my PhD thesis report and since my university does not have a template (too sad) I am making my own. I would like to know please what documentclass to use, is it book, article or, report?

Thanks in a advance :)

Comment: Templates don't have a great reputation, so I'd not be too disappointed. I'm not sure there is an objective answer there: I favour `report` but that's a personal preference.

Comment: Both `report` and `book` should be fine (As a European, I actually favor `scrreprt` and  `scrbook`, respectively, but that's a personal choice.) Some people swear by the `memoir` class. From your selection, `article` is probably least suited.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh really? I had no idea! Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: @Ingmar It is a french PhD thesis but I am writing in English. Understood, thank you!

Comment: @Wallflower: It's not about the language, it's about layout and typography. KOMA-Script already does a lot of the things for you (using A4 paper, some font changes, etc.) Obviously either can be made to work. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73141/why-should-i-not-use-the-koma-script-classes/73146

Comment: @Ingmar Oh ok, I get it now, thanks :)

Comment: The big thing is to find out the university requirements and adjust geometry etc. accordingly.  I don't suppose it would do any good to tell them that "double spacing" only applies to typewriters, not typesetters.

Comment: I suggest using the `memoir` class (warning: I'm the original developer). It enables you to do many things. The documentation (`> texdoc memoir`) includes a 17 page chapter *Twenty-one --- An example thesis design* which may prove useful.

Comment: @PeterWilson Pleasure to read from you. Will do, thank you!