# What are the benefits of using the KOMA-Script classes (scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook) instead of the default article, report and book classes?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes

The title mostly explains my question. I have seen many people recommend using KOMA-Script document classes instead of the default LaTeX classes. What do these classes offer that the default ones do not?

Comment: A couple of google hits: [What are the strengths and weaknesses of KOMA-Script and memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7742/82917), [Why should I *not* use the KOMA-Script classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73141/82917), [Most useful additions in KOMA-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1351/82917).

Comment: @campa I looked at some of these, but they don't really answer my question, which is why KOMA would be better than the default LaTeX classes.

Comment: The [accepted answer in the third link of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1360/82917) contains a list of features that KoMa classes have and the standard classes have not, so if I'm not misunderstanding your question it should be more or less the kind of answer you are expecting. If not, then please clarify why the linked answer is not enough.

Comment: I would argue that there are **no** advantages to using KOMA and the whole thing was an exercise in personal aesthetics, but that is just my opinion.  More importantly, there is LaTeX, Beamer, and KOMA, and they have very little in common.