# any nice book templates for math-based topics?

Tags: books

I am looking around for nice book templates, and I am quite disappointed. I found similar questions on tex.stackexchange (e.g. [Good LaTeX template for book about maths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28052/good-latex-template-for-book-about-maths)), but the book templates usually offered are either "book", "amsbook" or springers book template.

All of them I find rather disappointing, I am looking for something slightly more colorful or more polished.

I guess publishers don't publish latex templates for their book style, but is there anyone who is aware of a book template which is more polished/professional-looking/colorful than the amsbook template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Some places where you can start: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99968 or even (to a lesser extent though) http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840

Comment: related: [How to add some visual style and pizzazz to course notes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34301)

Comment: you seem to have disregarded the suggestion that, for `amsbook`, there are a number of ["author packages"](http://www.ams.org/publications/monopackages) that modify the basic style for a more distinct look.  somewhat less boring styles include *graduate studies in math*, *pure and applied undergraduate texts*, *mathematical world*, and the smaller-format *student mathematical library*.  these are not distributed on ctan, but are readily available from a drop-down list on the ams web pages.