# What packages do I need to learn as developer to learn LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pstricks, learning

I am a web developer and I often have the need to convert the the webpage to `pdf`. I have just discovered latex and pretty much liked it.

But as there are many packages available , I am not into book publishing and stuff. I am confused how should I learn it and what minimum packages I need to learn.

My main requirements are

1. Mostly reports with 100 of pages of tables and very wide columns. So I will be mostly working with tables
2. I may also need to create some graphs and maps with some figures

What packages should I learn?

Comment: [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/15717) and packages used by TeX.SX community [results from polls at meta.tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1574/15717)

Comment: Googling `html2tex` finds links to several tools that may help you get started. You can see what kind of `TeX` they produce from your input, and what packages they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For table, you need [longtable](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.
2. For making graphs or diagrams, you need [pstricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) package and its friends. As an alternate for PSTricks, you can choose TikZ, Asymptote, Metapost.
3. For importing figures, you need [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: do i need koma script . somene was saying that will do everything

Comment: @user17: I don't think koma script can be used for the second item above.

Comment: @user17  [koma script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) are a bun­dle of ver­sa­tile classes and pack­ages like article,book,etc classes. Refer [What are the strengths and weaknesses of KOMA-Script and memoir?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7742/15717)

Comment: I would add the geometry package.  It's useful for widening the text (decreasing the margins)

Comment: There is a link in [CTAN](http://ctan.org), labelled 'Topic'. I'd definitely recommend a look at the [tables topic](http://ctan.org/topic/table), if that's what you're after (mainly). As with most things, just as with apps, 'there is a package for that'. `:)`